# How can I add tab to tabbed page programatically with its associated view model?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add the tabs to the tabbed page programmatically. I can have only one content page and one ViewModel associated with each other, I want to add this content page multiple times with its associated ViewModel.
**My use case is, I am doing one survey app there will be multiple(say n number) categories of surveys. For each category, there will be one survey tab created with its associated ViewModel.** How to do this in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabs = new TabbedPage();

var vm1 = new SurveyVM(...);
var vm2 = new SurveyVM(...);
...
var vmn = new SurveyVM(...);

tabs.Children.Add(new SurveyPage(vm1));
tabs.Children.Add(new SurveyPage(vm2));
...
tabs.Children.Add(new SurveyPage(vmn));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am setting a binding context for each view but only one of the pages is showing the data but data is showed from only the last(nth) ViewModel instance. When I change tab its associated ViewModel is not loading the data.

Comment: without seeing code there is not way I can help you

Comment: it sounds like a VM issue, have you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: I checked my code It was VM issue. Now my code is working

Comment: @RahulMugali Thanks for your sharing, Please share your comment to answer.